# Android layouts: group dynamic elements

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

i have a view with image and text elements. Some of them are dynamic, so i want to group them inside a "container" (linear layout maybe?), so when some of them are not there, the below elements could have a margin of 20dp, instead of a big white space.

This is the layout:

[image: image layout]

My code:
(i want to group: phoneTitleTextView, homePhoneTextView and homeTitleTextView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:id="@+id/contactTitleTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/contactNameTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contactTitleTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/company"
        android:id="@+id/companyTitleTextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/companyTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactNameTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/companyTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactNameTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contactNameTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:id="@+id/phoneTitleTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/largeImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/homePhoneTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:id="@+id/homeTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homePhoneTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:id="@+id/addressTitleTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homePhoneTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/address1TextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addressTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/address2TextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address1TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/birthday"
        android:id="@+id/birthdayTitleTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address2TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/birthdayTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/birthdayTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:id="@+id/emailTitleTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/birthdayTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/starImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contactTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/homeTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/homeTitleTextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i try to do it with a relativelayout all my elements mix together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mentioned linearlayout, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RelativeLayout` you have to specify the position of each View **relative** to another. For example, to place `phone_02_title` below `phone_01_title` you would use the attribute `below` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    ...>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_01_title"
        ... 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_02_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_01_title"
        ... 
        />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway, if what you want is to set a margin between "phone" and "address" groups, I suggest you use `android:paddingBottom=""`. This places a spaces below the list, independently of how many rows the group has.

In case you want to leave a "free space" for the missing views (let's say you have 2/5 phones) I would rather set a fixed height for the container and rows. For example 40dp for each TextView's height and 200dp (5x40 dp) for their container.

Last but not least, I would also suggest you to use "setVisibility" for the views and not to add them dynamically, provided you know they will be between 1 to 5. Set all 5 views in your XML layout and then, programmatically, use `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and  `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` to show/hide their content (but not their height).

Hope any of this helps you!

Comment: Thanks!! fixed my issue, and thanks for the advice of SetVisibility, i'll use it!

Comment: Very glad I could help :)